# Getting all the filenames (not content) recursively from an http directory

Tags: wget, https

A large biological research project has chosen to make its archive available via https here:

https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/

Unfortunately, it appears that there is no manifest of the contents of these directories, so I simply want to build one.  I'd like to grab the filenames for the entire directory tree.  Are there any suggestions for how to do this?  I can write something up in perl/python/R/etc. to scrape the index.html files recursively, but I thought there might be some incantation with wget that can get me the filenames but I have not found that yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually had the *exact same problem*. Both of these solutions didn't work for me. However, this did:

Install lftp, then do

```
lftp https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/
du -a > manifest.txt
```

and that'll give you all the directories and file names.

Comment: 2023-03-27: I don't know the details, but a slight change worked for me. `lftp -c du -a the_url >& the_file_to_store_everything`. YMMV

Answer (score 5):

Opposed to the FTP protocol, HTTP does not know the concept of a directory listing. Thus, `wget` can only look for links and follow them according to certain rules the user defines.

That being said, if you absolutely want it, you can abuse `wget`s debug mode to gather a list of the links it encounters when analyzing the HTML pages. It sure ain't no beauty, but here goes:

```
wget -d -r -np -N --spider -e robots=off --no-check-certificate \
  https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/ \
  2>&1 | grep " -> " | grep -Ev "\/\?C=" | sed "s/.* -> //"
```

Some sidenotes:

- This will produce a list which still contains duplicates (of directories), so you need to redirect the output to a file and use `uniq` for a pruned list.
- `--spider` causes `wget` not to download anything, **but it still will do a HTTP HEAD request on each of the files it deems to enqueue**. This will cause a lot more traffic than is actually needed/intended and cause the whole thing to be quite slow.
- `-e robots=off` is needed to ignore a `robots.txt` file which may cause `wget` to not start searching (which is the case for the server you gave in your question).
- If you have `wget` 1.14 or newer, you can use `--reject-regex="\?C="` to reduce the number of needless requests (for those "sort-by" links already mentioned by @slm). This also eliminates the need for the `grep -Ev "\/\?C="` step afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I thought there would be a way to do this easily with wget/curl too but couldn't get anything to work either. You can use this Ruby gem, [anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/), to do it fairly easily though.

#### Installing anemone gem

```
% gem install anemone
Fetching: robotex-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: anemone-0.7.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed robotex-1.0.0
Successfully installed anemone-0.7.2
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for robotex-1.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for anemone-0.7.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for robotex-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for anemone-0.7.2...
```

#### Sample anemone script

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
require 'anemone'

Anemone.crawl("https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
      puts page.url
  end
end
```

#### Example run

```
% ./anemone.rb | grep -v '?C='
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/README_BCR.txt
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/README_MAF.txt
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/acc/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/brca/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/blca/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/cesc/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/cntl/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/dlbc/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/coad/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/esca/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/gbm/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/hnsc/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/kich/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/kirc/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/kirp/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/lcll/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/laml/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/lcml/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/lihc/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/lgg/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/lnnh/
https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcgafiles/ftp_auth/distro_ftpusers/anonymous/tumor/lost+found/
...
...
```

**NOTE:** The bit `grep -v '?C='` is filtering the boilerplate headers that Apache is generating via its Indexing directive, i.e.:

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable
```

[image: ss of apache rendered column sorter]

These allow you to sort the pages by the different columns (Name, Create Date, etc.). These show up as pages and I'm just filtering them out of the output.